# Authenticate User from c# Class Library - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Not sure if this is possible but here we go:

Our MVC website has currently been redesigned. Previously, we had the had the Logon button as an image, and if the user was authenticated, a logout button would be displayed. Like so:

```
<%
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
%>
<a href="/Account/LogOff">
    <img src="/images/logout.png" alt="logout" border="0" />
</a>
<%
    }
    else
    {
%>
<a href="<%: Url.Action("LogOn","Account")%>">
    <img src="/Images/login.png" alt="Log On" border="0" />
</a>
<%
    }
%>
```

The way the website has been designed however, the login button is now incorporated in the navigation menu. As we have multiple areas within the site, we use a c# method class from within a Helper class to generate the menus from the sitemap, like so:

```
public static string TabbedMenu(this HtmlHelper html, string area)
{
    // Get all the current information.
    //
    RouteData route = html.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData;
    string controller = route.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string action = route.GetRequiredString("action");

    StringBuilder menuWrapper = new StringBuilder();
    menuWrapper.Append("<ul id=\"main-nav\" class=\"nav fl\">");

    // Using the sitemap, build a tabbed menu.
    //
    foreach (SiteMapNode node in SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.Title == area)
        {
            foreach (SiteMapNode node2 in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node2["controller"].ToLower() == controller.ToLower())
                {
                    menuWrapper.Append("<li class=\"menu-item current-menu-item\">");
                }
                else
                {
                    menuWrapper.Append("<li class=\"menu-item\">");
                }

                RouteValueDictionary values = new RouteValueDictionary(new { Action = node2["action"], Controller = node2["controller"], Area = node2["area"] });
                VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPathForArea(html.ViewContext.RequestContext, values);
                string target = vpd.VirtualPath;

                menuWrapper.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", target, node2.Title);

                menuWrapper.Append("</li>");
            }
            break;
        }
    }


    menuWrapper.Append("<li id=\"menu-item-143\" class=\"login menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-143\"><a href=\"#\">Login</a></li>");
    menuWrapper.Append("<li id=\"menu-item-333\" class=\"menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-333\"><a href=\"#\">Sign up</a></li>");

    menuWrapper.Append("</ul>");

    return menuWrapper.ToString();
}
```

So my question really is, is there any way to authenticate the user from within this helper method?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: I see that you are adding separately the Login link to the menu, can't you just pass another boolean value to TabbedMenu which will contain the Request.IsAuthenthicated value and based on that add or not the menuitem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add new parameter to that function:

```
public static string TabbedMenu(this HtmlHelper html, string area, bool IsAuthenticated)
{
     ...
     if(IsAuthenticated)
         print something...
     else
         print something else...
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ile, Just what I'm looking for. Will mark as correct when the time limit is up.

Answer (score 3):

In you Class library project add the reference to System.Web.dll which allow you to access the HttpRequest like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```